# My male and female toggle button is not working in bmi calculator

Tags: flutter, dart, calculator

Since i had moved my Gesturedetector widgit into reusable_child.dart file my app became non functional. Please someone help me to fix the issue of male female toggle

Previously when then entire code was in one file(i.e BODY.dart) it was working properly this issue came after i created sepearte dart files for each

**BODY.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'reusable_card.dart';
import 'reusable_child.dart';
import 'AppDrawer.dart';

const double bottomContainerHeight = 80.0;
const Color containerColours = Color(0xFF1D1E33);
const Color inactiveContainerColor = Color(0xFF111328);

enum GenderType {
  MALE,
  FEMALE,
}

class BODY extends StatefulWidget {
  const BODY({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BODYState createState() => _BODYState();
}

class _BODYState extends State<BODY> {
  GenderType selectedGender = GenderType.MALE;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: AppDrawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
          child: Text('BMI Calculator'),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    colour: selectedGender == GenderType.MALE
                        ? containerColours
                        : inactiveContainerColor,
                    cardChild: ReusableChild(
                      containerIcon: FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                      txt: 'MALE',
                    ),
                    onPress: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender = GenderType.MALE;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    cardChild: ReusableChild(
                      containerIcon: FontAwesomeIcons.venus,
                      txt: 'FEMALE',
                    ),
                    colour: selectedGender == GenderType.FEMALE
                        ? containerColours
                        : inactiveContainerColor,
                    onPress: () {
                      selectedGender = GenderType.FEMALE;
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ReusableCard(
              onPress: () {},
              colour: containerColours,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    onPress: () {},
                    colour: containerColours,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    onPress: () {},
                    colour: containerColours,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.pink.shade400,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: bottomContainerHeight,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(17.0),
              child: Text(
                'Calculate',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**resuable_card.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard({
    required this.colour,
    this.cardChild,
    this.onPress,
  });
  final Color colour;
  final Widget? cardChild;
  final VoidCallback? onPress;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        child: cardChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          color: colour,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**resuable_child.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class ReusableChild extends StatelessWidget {
  final containerIcon;
  final String txt;
  ReusableChild({this.containerIcon = FontAwesomeIcons.amazon, this.txt = ''});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Icon(
          containerIcon,
          color: Color(0xFFffffff),
          size: 80.0,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Text(
          txt,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 18.0,
            color: Colors.grey.shade500,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is in your FEMALE ReusableCard's `onPress`

```dart
onPress: () {
  selectedGender = GenderType.FEMALE;
},
```

you forgot to add `setState` here as well

```dart
onPress: () {
  setState(() {
    selectedGender = GenderType.FEMALE;
  });
},
```

Comment: Thanks sir for solving my issue i have one query in reusable_card.dart, in  final Widget? cardChild; what does ? specify here

Comment: glad it worked, it means that your cardChild is nullable.

Comment: you can learn more [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety#:~:text=The%20Dart%20language%20now%20supports,into%20edit%2Dtime%20analysis%20errors.)